# Why is my MacBook Pro stuck in recovery mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, recovery

A few days ago, I ran into an issue with my MacBook. Whenever I tried to turn it on, it would take hours to load and eventually boot to a black screen. I ended up fixing this issue by opening my Mac's recovery mode, and reinstalling MacOS, but today another issue arose.

I restarted my MacBook today, and was met with only my Mac's wallpaper. I was able to move my cursor around the wallpaper, but was unable to do anything else. I shut it down, and opened Recovery Mode. I succesfully performed First Aid on my internal disk using Disk Utility, and restarted my computer, only to once again launch into Recovery Mode. I've tried every method I could find to escape it, but I haven't been able too.

1. I once again performed First Aid on both my Internal and Disk Images, all of which were succesful. When performing First Aid on my internal Volume, there was a pause when checking both `catalog` and `catalog hierarchy`.
2. I reset my NVRAM/PRAM.
3. I reset my SMC.
4. I attempted to reinstall macOS, only to be met with the error message `An error occurred when preparing the installation. Try running this application again`, and 2 disk images named `Apple UDIF read-only compressed (zlib) Media` with the volume `OS X Base System` appeared in my Disk Utility. Now, when trying to perform First Aid ony Internal volume, there was a pause at `Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required`, before the error message `First Aid could not unmount the volume for repair`. I was also unable to unmount it. This issue was fixed on restart, although I remained stuck in Recovery Mode.
5. I attempted to launch the Mac on safe mode, which failed. The Apple logo that I usually saw on launch was replaced with a circle with a line through it, and when I let go of `shift` Recovery Mode was launched.
6. I attempted to launch single-user Mode, to create another admin profile. This was succesful, however when I tried to use the `/sbin/mount –uw /` and `/sbin/fsck -fy` commands, I was met with the error line `disk1s1: device is write locked`, and was unable to access `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone`, which would allow me to create a new admin profile. The `exit` command simply returned me to Recovery Mode.
7. I am unable to erase or restore the `OS X Base System volume`, or it's parent, `Apple disk image Media`.

I must've gone through all these steps multiple times, in as many different orders as I can, and nothing has changed.

I believed I've exhausted all available means of escaping Recovery Mode, and my next step would be to backup my files (I can still access the Terminal, and my files, from Recovery Mode), then restore or erase my internal disc volume. I'm fine with this as an option, but I would prefer an alternative. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I'm currently running a MacBook Pro 13" on macOS 10.12.6

Edit: [image: Disk Utility screen, with Internal volume shown both mounted and unmounted]
[image: Result of diskutil list command]

Comment: It sounds like the drive has died. Can you post a picture of the disk utility screen or result of diskutil list. Base System & image media are temporary structures only in Recovery

Comment: I concur - sounds like a hardware failure of the drive or its connector. On a related note, I noticed oncethat a secondary drive used to stop working properly and macOS used to act erratically when the system became hot - turns out the heat in the system was causing the drive's connector to malfunction, and the solution was to ensure that the system never became too hot.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added pictures of both. Would there be any way to save the MacBook if the drive is dead?